# Couldn't find file 'twitter/bootstrap' (ROR)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, spring-boot

Here is the link https://github.com/Gtar69/games

I got a problem [image]

I had done with procured as below

In Gemfile:

```
gem "bootstrap-sass"
```

In terminal

```
bundle install
```

In `app/assets/stylesheets/application.css`

```
*= require bootstrap
```

But the local server still can not show bootstrap formation because it said it can not find bootstrap...

Thanks for help~

Comment: if you are using `RVM` make sure you are using same gemset in which you installed that gem

Comment: also show the output of `bundle show`

Answer (score 7):

Follow the below steps:

1. Rename the file "application.css" to "application.css.scss".
2. Remove all the contents and only keep the line 
   `@import "bootstrap";` in this file.
3. Run the server using "rails s" and check to see if things are working for login form.

In-case of problems, comment.

[image]

Comment: That wasn't enough, also needed to un-comment line 
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( default.js default.css.scss ) in assets.rb in 
.\config\initializers

Answer (score 4):

**Please always follow the instructions for the gems you are using** (in this case, `bootstrap-saas`).

From its README:

> Import Bootstrap styles in app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss:
>
> ```
> @import "bootstrap-sprockets";
> @import "bootstrap";
> ```

And also (emphasis mine):

> Make sure the file has .css.scss extension (or .css.sass for Sass syntax). If you have just generated a new Rails app, it may come with a .css file instead. **If this file exists, it will be served instead of Sass, so remove it:**
>
> ```
> $ rm app/assets/stylesheets/application.css
> ```

There's no `application.css.scss` in [your project](https://github.com/Gtar69/games). Instead, I find a file `app/assets/stylesheets/application.css` that you are to remove.

If you follow the documentation, your app will not raise errors and look like this:

[image: Games Store with Bootstrap]

Answer (score 3):

I was using both `*= require bootstrap` line with `@import "bootstrap";` and that was the cause of the problem. Removed the `*= require bootstrap`. The problem gone.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend reading the instructions at https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass#a-ruby-on-rails. But for solving your problem you should rename application.css to application.css.scss

`$ mv app/assets/stylesheets/application.css app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss`

Be sure to include `@import "bootstrap";` inside the file.