# couldn't find file 'bootstrap' with type 'text/css'

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I got a problem when adding bootstrap into my rail project. The error message is given as:

> File to import not found or unreadable: bootstrap-sprockets.

[image: Output]

I have tried the following two solutions but none of them works for me.

*Solution 1*: [Couldn't find file 'twitter/bootstrap' (ROR)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25860638/couldnt-find-file-twitter-bootstrap-ror)

*Solution 2*: [Sprockets::FileNotFound couldn't find file 'bootstrap' with type 'text/css'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36359801/sprocketsfilenotfound-couldnt-find-file-bootstrap-with-type-text-css)

Comment: which gem are you using?

Comment: @ArunKumar My way of installing: step 1: gem "bower-rails", "~> 0.10.0"; step2: asset 'bootstrap'; step3: rake bower:install

Answer (score 6):

In [here](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass#a-ruby-on-rails)

It says,

1. Rename your application.css to application.scss.
2. Delete *= require self and require tree
3. Add @import bootstrap-sprockets and bootstrap at the last line of the file.

Hope this helps.

I had the same issue.

Answer (score 5):

First you need add gem **gem 'bootstrap-sass', '3.3.6'** to your Gemfile then
**bundle install** then you must

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
```

to your scss file. Hope it will help you.

Comment: Thanks! Adding gem 'bootstrap-sass' seemed to be the critical piece. Do the gems, 'bootstrap-sass' and 'rails-sass', overlap in functions? Do they conflict?

Answer (score 4):

If Bootstrap was installed with yarn, I found that reinstalling it solved the issue:

```
yarn add bootstrap
```